# I'm trying to create an inMemory database using Collections and generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm creating an inMemory database, when i save data should be findble by inserting the primary key, in the Output will be also the name and surname.

```
public class InMemoryDatabase <T extends Entity,U>{
    ArrayList<User> inmemoryDatabase= new ArrayList<>();
    public User save(User entity){
        inmemoryDatabase.add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
    public Optional<User> findOne(U id){
        for (User element: inmemoryDatabase){
            if (User.getId().equals(id)){
                return Optional.of(element);
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    List<User> findAll(InMemoryDatabase<Entity, String> comparator){
        inmemoryDatabase.sort((Comparator<? super User>) comparator);
        return inmemoryDatabase;
    }
}
```

This is the entity class:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>{
    abstract public T getId();
}
```

In the database i would like to save username (primary key), name and surname of different utents.

```
public class User {
    private static  String username;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public User(String username, String name, String surname) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public static String getId(){
        return username;
    }
    

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Username: "+getId() + "\nname: " + getName() + "\nSurname: " + getSurname();
    }
}
```

in the main function, when try to use the findOne method,i get "julian_prin" "Rares " and "Marian" but the expected Output is "julian_prin" "Julian" and "Prinot".
can someone help me, to fix that and make the Methode findOne work correctly please?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InMemoryDatabase<Entity, String> database = new InMemoryDatabase<Entity, String>();
        database.save(new User("rares_mar","Rares","Marian"));
        database.save(new User("julian_prin","Julian","Prinot"));
        System.out.println(database.findOne("julian_prin"));
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like User.username should not be static field - so 2 different instances of user will actually have 2 different usernames

Comment: I revamped your code into a working project. Posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276789/42274) on Code Review Stack Exchange where I asked if my handling of Java Generics is correct. I had also written an Answer here, but the Question closed before I could post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with your username field in User class. You declared it as static which means that its value belongs to the User class(it means that the username field is shared by every User object, i.e. there is only 1 username for all User objects).
So when you create two user objects

```
database.save(new User("rares_mar","Rares","Marian"));
database.save(new User("julian_prin","Julian","Prinot"));
```

the value of static username field changes from rares_mar to julian_prin

Because of it, you get julian_prin, rares, marian instead of julian_prin, julian, prinot.

What concerns the solution, you can easily delete the static keyword for username(and by that you make it unique for each individual User object).